# jquery datatable how to set iDisplayLength from server side in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

The user has saved a value in the database for this table with the value in int how much rows he will get displayed.
I see there is a MVP controller for this build by someone else but that is really really a thing i cant understand.

So how to set iDisplayLength on server side in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make an AJAX call to the server code to get it. You're already using jQuery, so use jQuery AJAX. It's in their documentation and very easy to use.

Comment: I read it but dont understand, can you help me with a lil bit of code here please?